# Solving a limit without l'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

My friend passed me a limit that (in his opinion) is resovable using only derivatives or similar method. 
Here is the limit: 
$$\lim_{x\to0}   \frac{\ln(1+x+x^2) - (e^x-1)}{x\sin(x)}$$ 
I tried to solve it using basic limits (the limit form clearly shows parts of notable limits) but my solution is $1$ that is wrong. Can someone solve it **avoiding** derivative methods or similar methods? Or my friend is right? Sorry for my english and thank you in advance (if what I've written is not enough please advice me)

*I'm supposed to solve it knowing only basic limits and algebric manipulation nothing more. Just as someone that started to do limits in his first steps*

Comment: Does not using derivatives also mean not using polynomial approximations, which of course have their basis in the derivatives of the relevant functions?

Comment: OP said "using only derivatives or similar methods". But I guess Taylor expansions would be to much.

Comment: I'm supposed to solve it knowing only basic limits and algebric manipulation nothing more. Just as someone that started to do limits in his first steps

Comment: @Dipok How do you know that e.g. $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$ then?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem (see second example but there are different ways to demostrate it using this theorem)

Comment: @Dipok And what about $(e^x-1)/x\to 1$? And how do you even define $e^x$ and $\sin x$ to start with?

Comment: @dipok: When you say you want to "only" use basic limits and algebraic manipulation, what do you mean exactly? How do you define $\ln$, $e^x$ and $\sin x$?

Comment: In this case I see parts of this following notable limits:$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{ln(1+x)}{x}=1$ $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$ and $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{sinx}{x}=1$

Comment: @Dipok Answer the question of mine and Martin's, please. What's your definition of $e^x$, $\ln x$ and $\sin x$? You have to define it somehow, else this doesn't make sense. As you should see from my answer, I see the whole answer using the following notable limits (+ your sine): \begin{align*}&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}{x^2}=\frac12\\&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\frac12\end{align*}

Comment: I mean they are function that I'm supposed to know. For algebraic manipulation I mean use multiplication and division ($\frac{x}{x}$ in this case) and finally the fundamental limits are given and you have to solve it using all this basic information

Comment: I know that it is not correct to solve it in this way but I wanted to know only if it is possible! If it isn't so no problem :) the answer would be "your friend is right" :)

Comment: @Dipok Your question is too vague to answer because you don't know what $e^x$ and $\sin x$ are. So I can't help you.

Comment: @user2345215 your answer is the way my friend would show me. Forgive me but I don't get your point, how should I define the two functions? Why I can't solve it because "I" don't know what they are? What do you mean? (thank you anyway for trying to help me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can prove it without knowing that
$$\ln(1+x)=x+x^2/2+o(x^2), e^x=1+x+x^2/2+o(x^2)\text{ and }\sin x=x+o(x),$$
This is well known and you actually know special cases of this, such as
\begin{align*}&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}x=1\iff \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)-x}x=0\iff \ln(1+x)=x+o(x)\\&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}x=1\iff \lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1-x}x=0\iff e^x=1+x+o(x)\end{align*}
If you know what I wrote at the beginning, you can easily compute the limit:
\begin{align*}&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x+x^2)-(e^x-1)}{x\sin x}=\\&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(x+x^2)-(x+x^2)^2/2+o(x^2)-(1+x+x^2/2+o(x^2)-1)}{x(x+o(x))}=\\&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x+x^2-x^2/2+o(x^2)-x-x^2/2+o(x^2)}{x^2+o(x^2)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{o(1)}{1+o(1)}=0\end{align*}

Comment: When you are using Taylor polynomials, you are using derivatives. I would not accept this solution. Method of Taylor polynomials is even stronger method than LHospital rule.

Comment: @Joseph Not necessarily. If the series definitions of the functions are used, then you don't need anything.

Comment: Yes. If you define functions as series, then your solution is elementary.

Answer (score 0):

$$\ln(1+x+x^2)\sim_0 x+x^2$$ and $$\sin x\sim_0 x$$

Moreover $$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+x^2\varepsilon(x)$$ if $x\to 0$ where $\lim_{x\to 0}\varepsilon(x)=0$

then $$...=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x+x^2-(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+x^2\varepsilon(x)-1)}{x^2}=\lim_{x\to 0}\varepsilon(x)=0$$

Comment: if the person who downvote could explain, it would be more constructive.

Answer (score 0):

You can answer the question using standard definitions of Taylor series expansions:

$\ln \left(1+x\right) = x - \dfrac{x^{2}}{2} + \dfrac{x^{3}}{3} - \ldots$ ,

$e^{x} = 1+x+\dfrac{x^{2}}{2!} + \ldots$
and
$\sin \left (x\right) = x - \dfrac{x^{3}}{3!} + \ldots$

Now the only expression we need to worry about expanding is the $\ln$ term
$$\ln \left(1+x+x^{2}\right) = \left(x+x^{2}\right) - \dfrac{\left(x+x^{2}\right)^{2}}{2} + \dfrac {\left(x+x^{2}\right)^{3}}{3} - \ldots$$

$$= x + x^{2} - \dfrac{x^{2}}{2}\left(1+x\right)^{2} + \dfrac{x^{3}}{3}\left(1+x\right)^{3} + \ldots$$
which after some expanding and collecting terms gives:

$$\ln \left(1+x+x^{2}\right) = x + \dfrac{1}{2}x^{2} - \dfrac {2}{3}x^{3} + \ldots$$

We substitute this series and the other series into the expression concerned:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac {\ln \left(1+x+x^{2}\right) - e^{x} + 1}{x\sin \left (x\right)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{x+\dfrac{1}{2}x^{2}-\dfrac{2}{3}x^{3}-\left(1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2!}+\dfrac{x^{3}}{3!}+\ldots\right) + 1}{x\left(x-\dfrac{x^{3}}{6}+\ldots\right)}$$

$$ = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{x+\dfrac{1}{2}x^{2}-\dfrac{2}{3}x^{3}- x - \dfrac{x^{2}}{2} - \dfrac{x^{3}}{6}-\ldots}{x^{2}-\dfrac{x^{4}}{6}+\ldots}$$

$$ = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{- \dfrac{5}{6}x^{3} + \ldots}{x^{2}-\dfrac{x^{4}}{6}+\ldots}$$

Divide through by the $x^{2}$ in the fraction to get:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac {\ln \left(1+x+x^{2}\right) - e^{x} + 1}{x\sin \left (x\right)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{ - \dfrac{5}{6}x + \ldots}{1 - \dfrac{x^{2}}{6}+\ldots} = 0$$

Comment: So we HAVE to use Taylor expansion to solve this limit?